# Vigenere with multiple encryption

Tags: vigenere

I have a school project about cryptography. The question is the following (will only give a short phrase as example, just want to know the method).
A text has been encoded with Vigenere 2 times. The ciphertext is FXFCKDKFCLMHOSPERVBOPDJ (it's Dutch btw, you won't really get plausible words because I cut it off). It has first been encoded with a cipher of 3 letters, and then with a cipher of 2 letters. The first letter of the 2nd cipher is an O.

Comment: Welcome to CryptoSE. Please provide some additional information about what you have tried so far to solve it and where you're stuck, else this question will likely be closed.

Comment: One thing you can try is to consider the two encryptions as one by gathering them in a single 6 letters key. If the first key is ABC and the second one GO, then the 6 letters key will be ABCABC+GOGOGO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vigenere ciphertext encrypted with another vigenere cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19353/vigenere-ciphertext-encrypted-with-another-vigenere-cipher). **Note:** this is one of the questions

Comment: @Bissi Shouldn't that be `ABCABC+OGOGOG`?